# python numpy cusum/sum performance

Tags: python, numpy, performance

We have a function that we use a lot. It uses a numpy array as input and a built-in np.cusum. I tried to implement it using native python for loop, but the Performance is not getting better. I'm not sure if there's anything to be done to make it faster. Here is the code I'm using to compare the implementations

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def implementation1(y):
    resids = y - np.mean(y)
    T = y.shape[0]
    test_stat = np.sum(np.cumsum(resids) ** 2) / (np.sum(resids ** 2) * T)
    return test_stat


def implementation2(y):
    resids = y - np.mean(y)
    T = y.shape[0]
    rs0 = resids[0]
    rss = rs0 * rs0
    scr2 = rss
    last = rs0
    for res in resids[1:]:
        rss = rss + res * res
        now = last + res
        scr2 = scr2 + now ** 2
        last = now
    test_stat = scr2 / (rss * T)
    return test_stat


def timefunc(func, n_seeds, n_point):
    durations = []
    for seed in range(n_seeds):
        np.random.seed(seed)
        y = np.random.random(n_point)
        start_time = timeit.default_timer()
        func(y)
        duration = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
        durations.append(duration)
        print(f"{seed}/{n_seeds - 1}")
    return durations


if __name__ == "__main__":
    duration1 = timefunc(implementation1, 100, 1000)
    duration2 = timefunc(implementation2, 100, 1000)

    plt.plot(duration1, label="implementation1")
    plt.plot(duration2, label="implementation2")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[image: compare result]

Comment: Have a look at numba. Maybe just adding `@numba.jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)` helps. At least you are using pure Python which should work out of the box. https://numba.pydata.org/

Comment: You are trying to speed up a function by using a python for loop instead of `numpy`?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Yes. One single scan over the data should be faster. Combining it with Numba was a better option than Numpy

Answer (score 1):

Using **just** python loops is not a good choice to be comparable by NumPy code in terms of performance. If there not be any restriction to use Numba library, you can get better performance by decorating the `implementation2` with Numba as:

```
@nb.njit("float64(float64[::1])", fastmath=True)
def implementation2(y):
    resids = y - np.mean(y)
    T = y.shape[0]
    rs0 = resids[0]
    rss = rs0 * rs0
    scr2 = rss
    last = rs0
    for res in resids[1:]:
        rss = rss + res * res
        now = last + res
        scr2 = scr2 + now ** 2
        last = now
    test_stat = scr2 / (rss * T)
    return test_stat
```

[image]